# Connection test working on netcat but not on telnet

Tags: kubernetes, telnet, netcat

I am doing a connection test from a pod in kubernetes using netcat and telnet and the test from netcat is working fine and not from telnet. The pod runs a nodejs container and the connectivity from nodejs application is also failing.

telnet from every other pod on the same node works fine. I am completely lost on to why this is happening

Comment: Can you provide more detail? In particular, what commands are executed where, and how they're failing.

Comment: netcat -zv <host> <port>
telnet <host> <port>

one thing to note here is that running netstat -antp shows this

tcp        0      0 10.244.4.244:58016      10.195.209.4:6380       ESTABLISHED 31/telnet

as established but telnet does not show anything.


All these are run inside the container exec' ing in to them

Comment: What do you expect the telnet to show? Is it giving an error, or just sitting there waiting input? If the latter, your pod might be expecting some input.

Comment: i was expecting the telnet to output saying established connection. its just sitting there waiting as of now. but the same telnet on a different pod says connection terminated by remote host

Comment: That sounds like the pod drops packages coming to that port. Maybe the iptables would provide a hint?

Comment: can you telnet using `kubectl port-forward`?

Comment: @Burak Serdar so i got to work with an MS engineer opening a support ticket and looks like the network connection is fine. still could not figure out the strange behavior in that pod. there is no service mesh or anything  messing with the iptables. we did checked iptables and haven't found anything significant in there.

Thanks all for your time.